# Removing a device in "removed" state from Linux software RAID array

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

My workstation has two disks(/dev/sd[ab]),  both with similar partitioning.  /dev/sdb failed,  and `cat /proc/mdstat` stopped showing the second sdb partition.

I ran `mdadm --fail` and `mdadm --remove` for all partitions from the failed disk on the arrays that use them,  although all such commands failed with

```
mdadm: set device faulty failed for /dev/sdb2:  No such device
mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sdb2: No such device or address
```

Then I hot swapped the failed disk,  partitioned the new disk and added the partitions to the respective arrays.  All arrays got rebuilt properly except one,  because in /dev/md2, the failed disk doesn't seem to have been removed from the array properly.  Because of this,  the new partition keeps getting added as a spare to the partition,  and its status remains degraded.

Here's what `mdadm --detail /dev/md2` shows:

```
[root@ldmohanr ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
    Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 27 22:55:14 2011
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 52427708 (50.00 GiB 53.69 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 52427708 (50.00 GiB 53.69 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Fri Nov 23 14:59:56 2012
      State : active, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

       Name : ldmohanr.net:2  (local to host ldmohanr.net)
       UUID : 4483f95d:e485207a:b43c9af2:c37c6df1
     Events : 5912611

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       0        0        1      removed

   2       8       18        -      spare   /dev/sdb2
```

To remove a disk,  mdadm needs a device filename,  which was /dev/sdb2 originally,  but that no longer refers to device number 1.  I need help with removing device number 1 with 'removed' status and making /dev/sdb2 active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the drive is no longer showing up in the system, do this:

`mdadm /dev/md2 -r detached`

or

`mdadm /dev/md2 -r failed`

If done successfully, you should get a message like:

> mdadm: hot removed 8:50 from /dev/md0

And the drive no longer shows up in /proc/mdstat.  **From the man page:**

> "The first causes all failed device to be removed.   The  second 
>   causes any device which is no longer connected to the system (i.e an
>   'open' returns ENXIO) to be removed.  This will only succeed for
>   devices that are spares or have already been marked as failed."

Comment: `mdadm /dev/mdX -r failed` is what helped me. The original (failed) disk was detached by the controller itself.